# 'Save edits' button has a green border on top when pressed

Tags: bug, design

When you press <kbd>Save edits</kbd> after editing a question or answer, the button turns grey but the top border stays green:

[image]

Comment: I have pointed the authorities to this post. Lets see what happens ;)

Comment: [I noticed a similar issue](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11445/shadow-of-vote-to-close-button-still-displays-after-button-is-pressed) on another site, it may be a network-wide issue.

Comment: Yes, we've been playing with buttons and colors recently network-wide. It should be ok now. Thanks for reporting!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting. This issue should be fixed now.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be fixed....